# XML node properties

Tags: javascript, html, xml

Firstly thanks for taking the time to look at this.  I have a personal website I am running and I have having a little trouble retrieving image url's to display.  Right now on my website page I have a few `<p>` and a `<img>` tag.  With the `<p>` tags I set innerHTML to different xml nodes to display the text in the XML nodes.  With the `<img>` I just use the Jquery arrt() function and set source to the text in the XML node (which is the image url).  This does work, however for some reason the page goes really slow.  Anybody have any ideas?

The page is justinmburrous.com/help/news.html and the js page is justinmburrous.com/help/javascript/news.js

I am guessing it is an xmlProperty issue, I have tried several different kinds and still can not seem to fix the issue.

Thanks.

Comment: please use code formatting (`{}`button) so that we can see the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its any indication, I saw a "Load Error" bit of text where the image should be... and then the image loaded - yep pretty slowly.

Also, part slowness could be from the nature of your images, they look unoptimised - 829KB for 'steamengine1.jpg' at 3264x1952 dimensions when downloaded.

Comment: 3,264px × 1,952px (scaled to 175px × 105px). I make that 6,352,953 pixels more than I need. It's about 347 times bigger than it needs to be.

Comment: Yeah, the load error is in there incase there is no image to display.  Its an error message I added.  I know my images are incredible large and not great for quick load time, however my issue is that the page freezes up.  The canvas animation in the background stops and the animations are laggy.  Thats what I cant  figure out.  Do you have a similar problem?  There is a major difference with the other pages.

Comment: If you're not already, I recommend using Firefox and an extension like YSlow which waterfalls the scripts and such on your pages as it loads. It should give you a decent indication of any bottlenecks. If its your preference, like mine, I use Chrome's Developer extension to do a similar task.

Comment: I use chrome, but I use other browsers occasionally.  I will check out the developer tools.  Thanks.

Comment: Okay just to finish this up, it was the web picture size.  I did not know that after the picture was loaded it has trouble rendering a large size image.  Not it works.  Thanks for your help and James Walford you were of course correct, I did not think that mattered.

Comment: Glad you confirmed our results :) That catches many of my designers out continuously, thankfully its an easy one to spot once you've seen it a few times.

Comment: You can check my answer as 'correct', if you'd consider it so - that would officially 'finish this off' :)